# increment operator vs. i + 1 in loop

Tags: javascript, loops, increment, operator-keyword, operands

```js
let eachScore = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];

let numOfScores = eachScore.length;

let roundNum = 0;

let msg = '';

// if i change (i + 1) to i++, the loop doesn't work as expected

for (i = roundNum; i < numOfScores; i++) {

  msg += 'Round' + (i + 1) + ': ' + eachScore[i] + '<br/>';

}

document.querySelector("#round").innerHTML = msg
```

```html
<div id="round"></div>
```

This is the code I wrote.
I understand why `i++` **doesn't work** as expected.

The loop literally increments the i every time it sees i++, but it doesn't increment for (i + 1).

I don't see why i++ and (i + 1) aren't the same. Why (i + 1) doesn't increment just like i++ does?

I saw the definition of increment operator. It just says increment operator adds one to its operand and returns a value, which seems like it's saying i++ is the same as (i + 1)...

Comment: `i + 1` is not the same as `i++` because the latter mutates the value, and the former just evaluates a math expression, returns the final result and leaves `i` untouched.

Comment: `i++` is (roughly) equivalent to `i = i + 1`, which is rather obviously different from `i + 1` alone.

Comment: `(i + 1)` returns the mathematical addition of `i + 1`. It does not modify `i` to be `i + 1`, so saying `i` later on will still be the original value of `i`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. MDN documentation for [++A](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment) says

> The increment operator (++) increments (adds one to) its operand and returns a value.

which is unfortunate as it doesn't clarify what's going on and why use "pre" (or "post")  to qualify "increment".

To pre-increment a variable means to get the value of the variable from memory, add one to it, store the result back in memory and return the addition result as the result of the pre-increment operator. It's called "pre" increment because incrementation occurs before returning the updated value of the variable to the program.

In contrast, to post increment a variable means to get the current value of the variable from memory, make a copy of it (perhaps in a CPU register), increment the value and save it back in memory - and then return the copied value the variable had before the addition took place. It called "post" increment because incrementation occurs after getting the value to return to the program.

Of course, `(i+1)` just gets the value of `i`, adds one to it and returns the result of the expression without updating the value of `i`.

---

*A more precise version of the MDN article could include "[l-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)#Assignment:_l-values_and_r-values)" in the glossary and describe the operator along the lines of:*

The increment operator (++) is a unary assignment operator that increments its operand in storage and returns a result. The operand must be an [l-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)#Assignment:_l-values_and_r-values).

- If `++` is used as a prefix operator,  the incremented value of the operand is returned as the result of the operation.
- If `++` is used as a postfix operator, the value of the operand before being incremented is returned as the result of the operation.

Answer (score 1):

`(i+1)` is a number. It is returning `Whatever i is` plus 1.

`i++` is a mutator. It is setting `i` to be `Whatever I is` plus `1`.
As per @Samathingamajig :

> "i++ mutates i as i = i + 1. but the value returned from it was the
> previous value of i, so it is a bit different from i = i + 1. ++i does
> the same mutation but returns the new value of i."

Iteration happens so much developers just found it easy to have shorthand, but you should always think of `i++` as being the same as `i=i+1`

`For` loops usually follow the format of:

for(`condition that needs to be met`;`end condition of loop`;`What to do at the end of each loop`)
In your example, you are saying `What to do at  the end of each loop` is `Set i to whatever i is plus 1`